# How can I update only a single cell value and JSON in table

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a code where I have a table of 3 columns. the last column is editable. My requirement is, when I click on that cell, add a new value, and it should update the corresponding value in the JSON.

Currently, I'm

1. Unable to enter a value in the cell (though it is editable).
2. Unable to know how I can update the JSON.

Here is my code.

```
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { useEffect } from "react";
const csvArray = [
  { Name: "user 1", Age: "12", Rank: "2" },
  { Name: "user 2", Age: "13", Rank: "3" },
  { Name: "user 3", Age: "10", Rank: "2" },
  { Name: "user 4", Age: "16", Rank: "1" },
  { Name: "user 5", Age: "14", Rank: "5" }
];
const keys = ["Name", "Age", "Rank"];
const RenderTable = () => {
  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("noBorder");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("border");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(csvArray));
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.readOnly = false;
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("noBorder");
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("border");
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {keys.map((item, idx) => (
              <TableCell key={idx}>{item}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {csvArray.map((item, idx) => (
            <TableRow>
              {keys.map((key, idx) =>
                key === "Rank" ? (
                  <TableCell>
                    <input
                      class="noBorder"
                      type="true"
                      readOnly="true"
                      value={item[key]}
                      onBlur={(e) => handleBlur(e)}
                      onClick={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                    ></input>
                  </TableCell>
                ) : (
                  <TableCell> {item[key]} </TableCell>
                )
              )}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default RenderTable;
```

Here it is in action https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-pine-pddi4l?file=/src/RenderTable.js:0-2161. Where am I going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added csvArrayState state to control change. The issue you're having pertains to control. Yes you did change the type and made ranks editable but you lacked control. This snippet adds that control.

```
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { useState } from "react";
const csvArray = [
  { Name: "user 1", Age: "12", Rank: "2" },
  { Name: "user 2", Age: "13", Rank: "3" },
  { Name: "user 3", Age: "10", Rank: "2" },
  { Name: "user 4", Age: "16", Rank: "1" },
  { Name: "user 5", Age: "14", Rank: "5" }
];
const keys = ["Name", "Age", "Rank"];
const RenderTable = () => {

  const [csvArrayState, setCsvArrayState] = useState(() => 
    csvArray);

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("noBorder");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("border");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(csvArrayState));
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.readOnly = false;
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("noBorder");
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("border");
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {keys.map((item, idx) => (
              <TableCell key={idx}>{item}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {csvArray.map((item, i) => (
            <TableRow>
              {keys.map((key, idx) =>
                key === "Rank" ? (
                  <TableCell>
                    <input
                      class="noBorder"
                      type="true"
                      readOnly="true"
                      value={csvArrayState[i].Rank}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const updatedRankFields = csvArrayState.map((r, rIdx) => {
                          if (rIdx === i) {
                            return { ...r, Rank: e.target.value };
                          } else {
                            return r;
                          }
                        });
                        setCsvArrayState(updatedRankFields);
                      }}
                      onBlur={(e) => handleBlur(e)}
                      onClick={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                    ></input>
                  </TableCell>
                ) : (
                  <TableCell> {item[key]} </TableCell>
                )
              )}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default RenderTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for this buddy. I'm able to edit the rank data, but I don't think the data is getting updated :( . I tested it by adding a `console.log(JSON.stringify(csvArray))` inside `handleBlur()`.

Comment: @Rakesh Glad I can be of help. I edited the code. I think handleBlur() should now log the entire csvArray with rank field updated.

Comment: Please notice that csvArrayState is what's being manipulated. Not your original csvArray. So I'm logging that.

Comment: You are awesome mate :-). one last question I've is I get a warning `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` Here I'm using `idx` to loop (Hope I'm doing it the right way).

Comment: Cheers mate. I'd say it's because TableRow is not utilizing any key but I'm not really familiar with MUI so that's on you :)